# Prove that the points $A(-2,1,3)$, $B(1,2-4)$ and $C(-2,2,1)$ form a triangle.

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles

I have points $A(-2,1,3)$, $B(1,2-4)$ and $C(-2,2,1)$.

Do points $A,B,C$ form a triangle?

If it does how can I prove.

Comment: Just prove that they are not in the same line. That is, that $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ are not proportional (parallel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation through $A$ and $B$ is
$$\frac{x+2}{3}=\frac{y-1}{1}=\frac{z-3}{-7}$$
and the point $C$ does not satisfy the above equation. Thus, the three points do not belong in a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $A(x_1,y_1,z_1), B(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. Then
$$AB=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$$
Prove that

$AB+BC>AC$ and $AC+BC>AB$ and $AB+AC>BC$